Unable to parse interactions in Discord.js
I'm making a discord bot that generates images based on user's input using OpenAI. After I ran my main file, index.js, I typed a prompt formy command to test it out. It did generate the image and logged in the console the image's url, but then,it was unable to send the same image. I went through the error,
Here's my index.js file:
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

/* This block of code is iterating over each folder in the `commands` directory and then for each file
within those folders that ends with `.js`, it requires the file and checks if it has both a `data`
and `execute` property. If the required properties are present, it adds the command to the
`client.commands` Collection with the command's name as the key. If the required properties are
missing, it logs a warning message indicating that the command file is missing the necessary
properties. */
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (readyClient) => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});

/* This block of code is handling interactions created by users in a Discord server. */
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});

client.login(token);

Here's my commands/generate_images.js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const OpenAI = require("openai");
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: "sk-proj-my-api-key",
});

/**
 * This code block is defining a Discord slash command handler
    for generating high-quality AI images using the OpenAI API.
 */
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("generate-images")
    .setDescription("Generate High Quality AI Images Using The Best Model!")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("prompt")
        .setDescription("Prompt")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const promptInput = interaction.options.getString("prompt");

    if (!promptInput) {
      // Handling case where prompt is not provided
      interaction.reply("Please provide a prompt.");
      return;
    }
    
    try {
      const response = await openai.images.generate({
        model: "dall-e-3",
        prompt: promptInput,
        n: 1,
        size: "1024x1024",
      });

      console.log("Response:", response); // Add this line
      interaction.reply(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      interaction.reply("An error occurred while generating the image.");
    }
  },
};

Here's the error:
     throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:722:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:826:23)  
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\discord-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1266:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1231599602235605074/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzMTU5OTYwMjIzNTYwNTA3NDpTQ0d2WjZUUENrbmVabHJzY29rSDZ2SmFrUVpCbTdoODZqZUcwQ3VWa0JFU3RoUHpYMHJpZzl6cXFHTnVJN1dycUNicXJTVFhZNzFMRDFoZkF4aW9pbm9XSlkzNkNTSndzakJhV09rWVp5cklKeUhVRVF2MThoeEJ0a2xlOEJvaw/callback'
}

Here's https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1231599602235605074/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzMTU5OTYwMjIzNTYwNTA3NDpTQ0d2WjZUUENrbmVabHJzY29rSDZ2SmFrUVpCbTdoODZqZUcwQ3VWa0JFU3RoUHpYMHJpZzl6cXFHTnVJN1dycUNicXJTVFhZNzFMRDFoZkF4aW9pbm9XSlkzNkNTSndzakJhV09rWVp5cklKeUhVRVF2MThoeEJ0a2xlOEJvaw/callback
// 20240421191342
// https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1231599602235605074/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzMTU5OTYwMjIzNTYwNTA3NDpTQ0d2WjZUUENrbmVabHJzY29rSDZ2SmFrUVpCbTdoODZqZUcwQ3VWa0JFU3RoUHpYMHJpZzl6cXFHTnVJN1dycUNicXJTVFhZNzFMRDFoZkF4aW9pbm9XSlkzNkNTSndzakJhV09rWVp5cklKeUhVRVF2MThoeEJ0a2xlOEJvaw/callback

{
  "message": "405: Method Not Allowed",
  "code": 0
}

I changed the code many times but it didn't work.

If you are getting unknown interaction in the console chances are likely that the interaction is getting timed out to avoid that you can add a deferReply method, which sends a initial reply of bot is thinking. And the instead of doing intearaction.reply you should do interaction.editReply.
I think that should solve the issue.
Regarding 4O5 method error it was solved for me when I corrected the syntax and switched to djs 14.
